# Clarification: intersection of a finite number of subgroups of finite index and Poincaré

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, math-history

From Scott's book *Group Theory*

> $1.7.10.$ (Poincaré) The intersection of a finite number of subgroups of finite index is of finite index.

My question is: Did Poincaré prove the Theorem as stated above or something like that? I mean,  was he interested in Group Theory or he proved something which resembles the theorem stated above

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: I know that Poincare introduced the notion of the fundamental group. It stands to reason that he had some interest in group theory.

Comment: Poincaré was one of the early pioneers of group theory, and especially of using topological and geometric methods to do it (along with Nielsen and Dehn - see "Combinatorial Group Theory" by Lyndon and Schupp). I can see no reason to doubt that this theorem was due to him.

Comment: There are two votes to close this question as "not constructive". This seems to be a perfectly legitimate question in the history of mathematics, maybe phrased in a slightly unfortunate way.

Comment: This question is part of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/351983/49437) (with no answer). I suppose we don't need two versions of the same question open, but the system insists.