# Which theorem did Poincaré prove?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, math-history

Two related elementary facts in group theory are sometimes called Poincaré's theorems.

- If $H\lneq G$ and $[G:H]<\infty$, then there is $N\leq H$, $N\lhd G$ such that $[G:N]<\infty$.
- The intersection of a finite number of subgroups of finite index is of finite index.

Did he prove both? Could you please give me references to the paper(s) (or at least the year(s))? I'm especially interested in the first one, but I would prefer to know the whole story.

Comment: I can't really recall the proofs at the moment, but isn't the first statement an easy corollary of the second one?

Comment: @tomasz: The first statement follows from the second one by using $N = \cap_{x \in G} xHx^{-1}$

Comment: I have edited the first point - you need $H$ to be a proper subgroup (or $N$ has to be equal to $G$ sometimes, and the theorem is trivial!)

Comment: Also, if your group is finitely generated then there are only finitely many subgroups of a given index. Thus, intersect them all and you get a *characteristic* subgroup. Which is cool!

Comment: Most of the time the second statement is attributed to Poincaré. Not sure about the "n!-Theorem" as the first is occasionally referred to. This is more Cauchy- or Lagrange-like. I guess we have to dig up the original papers of Poincaré, and still then I expect these theorems be part of something bigger than these statements alone.

Comment: @user1729: even if it's trivial, it's still true... most theorems have cases where they are trivial.

Comment: @tomasz: What was written is vacuously true. The proof is trivial. It is *not* Poincare's theorem. Also, Bartek wrote $N\lhd G$, at which point the statement becomes false (as $G$ is not a proper subgroup of itself).

Comment: @user1729: hardly; it is only trivial in case when $H=G$, but $H$ was arbitrary. It is vacuously true in this case, but is still true for arbitrary $H$, including $G$. I don't think there is a standard convention on whether $\lhd$ means the same as $\unlhd$ or not. The theorem says that any subgroup of finite index has a subgroup which is a normal subgroup of finite index. You could say that it is vacuously true for any normal subgroup, but it doesn't mean you have to go out of your way to state that $H$ is not normal...

Comment: @tomasz: Oh, sorry, I understand what you mean now. With respect to notation, I always assume $\lhd$ is proper. I know that there is no general consensus, but I do feel that it isn't asking to much for people to use words to be more specific, or to use better notation (\lneq: $\lneq$ or \unlhd: $\unlhd$)...

Comment: There was an earlier question on the second bullet (no answer): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/104573/49437