# Poincaré's theorem about groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group and $H<G$ such that $[G:H]<\infty$. There exists a subgroup $N\triangleleft G$ such that $[G:N]<\infty$.

I have to show this fact (that according to my book is due to Poincaré), but I think that the statement, written in this way, is trivial: for every group $G$, I can take $N=G$, in fact $G\triangleleft G$ and $[G:G]=1$.

Where am I wrong?

If I'm not wrong, do you know a similar statement?

Comment: you might want to add group actions tag for this.... This could also be taken as a hint...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: hint to show what? is the statement not trivial as I think?

Comment: It would be trivial if you consider trivial subgroup and would be non trivial if you want to look for non trivial subgroups....

Comment: just tell me one thing.. are you familiar with group actions?

Answer (score 8):

The non-trivial version of the statement is that $N$ can be taken to be a subgroup of $H$.  In other words, the collection of finite index *normal* subgroups is cofinal in the collection of all finite index subgroups.

Comment: Is this an answer (proof) :O

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, have you understood the question? It is not about a proof, but about the correct statement.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks everyone for the answers, even if I just asked for the correct statement and not to spoiler me the solution. I'm not familiar with group actions, so (with Nicky's hint) I tried to write a different solution.

*Let $G$ be a group and $H<G$. If $[G:H]<\infty$, then there exists $N\triangleleft G$ such that $N\subseteq H$ and $[G:N]<\infty$.*

**Lemma 1.** Let $H^g:=gHg^{-1}$ and $N:=\bigcap_{g\in G}H^g$. Then $H^g<G$, $N\triangleleft G$ and $N\subseteq H$.

*Proof:* Straightforward.

**Lemma 2.** Let $n=[G:H]$, then there are at most $n$ subgroups of $G$ of the form $H^g$.

*Proof:* Let $gH$ be a left coset of $H$ in $G$. Let $a, b\in gH$, then $H^a=H^g=H^b$. But the $n$ left cosets partition $G$.

**Lemma 3.** Let $H, K< G$, then $[G:H\cap K]\le [G:H][G:K]$.

*Proof:* Observe that  for every $g\in G$, $g(H\cap K)=gH\cap gK$ and that we can choose $aH\cap bK$ in $[G:H][G:K]$ (not always different) ways.

**Lemma 4.** $[G:H]=[G:H^g]$.

*Proof:* Let $S:=\{xH:x\in G\}$ and $S^g:=\{xH^g:x\in G\}$. Define $f:S\rightarrow S^g$ such that $f(xH)=(gxg^{-1})H^g$. $f$ is well-defined and injective, in fact $xH=yH\Leftrightarrow xy^{-1}\in H\Leftrightarrow (gxg^{-1})(gyg^{-1})^{-1}=gxy^{-1}g^{-1}\in H^g \Leftrightarrow f(xH)=f(yH)$. Moreover, $f$ is surjective because $f(g^{-1}xgH)=xH^g$.

Now, putting things together, we have that $N$ defined in lemma 1 is the subgroup we wanted, because
$$[G:N]\le [G:H]^n=n^n.$$

Comment: If I would be your professor, I would have given you an $A^+$. Well done!

Comment: To get an $A^{++}$, try to get the $n^n$ down to $n!$.

Answer (score 2):

The question is: If there exists a finite index proper subgroup, prove that there exists a finite index proper normal subgroup.

The group $G$ acts by left multiplication on the left cosets of $H$. This action corresponds to a homomorphism $G\rightarrow S_n$ from $G$ to the symmetric group on $n$ elements (why?). (Note that this map is not necessarily surjective or injective - it is just some homomorphism.) This map has a kernel...

**Note:** This is the solution that Praphulla Koushik is getting at. There is a solution which does not use group actions, but if my memory serves me well it is significantly longer.

**Note II:** mesel's comments, below, regard an earlier version of the answer where the action was by conjugation. Unpacking the "why?" is harder in this case - you need to apply the orbit-stabiliser theorem to get the map $G\rightarrow S_m\leq S_n$ where $m=|G:N_H(G)|$ is the index of the normaliser of $H$ in $G$. The kernel of this map is $G$ itself if and only if the subgroup $H$ is normal.

Comment: I guess your solution is wrong.You said $G$ acts set of subgroups of index $n$.Then you will have homomorphism from $G$ to $S_k$ where $k$ is the number of subgroup of index $n$, which has no direct relation with $n$.But the idea is true, if I am wrong,correct me.

Comment: @mesel That is tied up in the "why?". However if I alter the action it makes it easier: rather than acting by conjugation act by left multiplication. I've edited the post.

Comment: let $G=Z$ and $H=2Z$ then $|G:H|=2$ and $H$ is uniqe subgroup of index 2. So,your action is trivial $\implies$ $N=G$ which is not proper.

Comment: Now, it is ok now . I think the requiered condition is $N\leq H$.
please see my answer also (now it is almost same).

Comment: @mesel If you act by conjugation then you are mapping to $S_m$ where $m$ is the index of the normaliser of $H$ in $G$. As $m\leq n$, this corresponds to a map to $S_n$. If the kernel is trivial then the subgroup itself is normal.

Comment: Which set are you acting?

Comment: @mesel On the conjugates of $H$. (This answer should have read "left multiplication" from the very beginning - conjugation was just a typo! However, the conjugation action tells you, in a certain sense, what is actually going on. The kernel of both actions is the intersection of all the conjugates of $H$, and is called the *normal core* of $H$. That the kernel is this is, perhaps, easier to see when you are acting by conjugation.)

Comment: Yes,exactly.I thought you again mean set of subgroup with index n.

Comment: @mesel It doesn't actually matter - you apply the orbit-stabiliser theorem to $H$ and then focus your attention there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13114/discussion-between-mesel-and-user1729)

Comment: @mesel Chat doesn't work for me for some reason. Sorry!

Comment: stabilizer of an element need not to be normal, am I wrong? What I mean the solution is not clear if you act on set of elements have index $n$.

Comment: @mesel Yes, the stabiliser of $H$ need not be normal, but the stabiliser is not the kernel of the action. The kernel $K$ of the action consists of those elements $k$ such that $H^{gk}=H^g$ for all $g\in G$, so $H^{gkg^{-1}}=H$. Thus, $K$ is the largest subgroup of $N_H(G)$ which is normal in $G$.

Comment: I am really tired. if you are acting the set of element which has index $n$ and if there is an another sungroup of $G$ with index n and which is not a conjugate of $H$ then The $K$ which you define is not the kernel.

Comment: @mesel i am tired too! Yes, yiu are right about the kernel. My $K$ is the kernel if you are only considering the orbit if $H$. So yes, let $G$ act on the conjugates of $H$...etc...

Comment: There is something not quite right in these comments - if $N_G(H)$ is normal then the kernel of the action is the normaliser $N_G(H)$. Thus, the two actions -left multiplication and conjugation- yield different kernels. Which wasn't what I noted above.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem follows from what is called *Poincaré's Lemma* in group theory.

**Lemma** Let $G$ be a group, $H$ and $K$ subgroups with *finite index*. Then the subgroup $H \cap K$ has finite index too.

**Proof** (sketch) for any $g \in G$, the coset $g(H \cap K) \subseteq gH \cap gK$.

The theorem now follows by observing that any conjugate $H^g$ of $H$ has the same (finite) index as $H$ in $G$ and the number of conjugates of $H$ is finite (it equals $[G:N_G(H)]$ which divides $[G:H]$).

Remark: see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104573/clarification-intersection-of-a-finite-number-of-subgroups-of-finite-index-and) discussion!

Answer (score 0):

I guess correct statement sholud require $N \leq H$.

Let $G$ act on left coset of $H$ by left multiplication.Then we have homomorphism from $\phi$ from $G$ to $S_{[G:H]}$.Thus,$|G:Ker(\phi)|divides |G:H|!$ so $|G:Ker(\phi)|$ is finite. $Ker(\phi)$ is desired normal subgroup.

Since elements of $Ker(\phi)$ fixes every elements by left multiplacition, so it also fixes $H$ $\implies$ $Ker(\phi)| \leq H$.(Actually it is the largest normal subgroup contained in $H$)

Comment: Anyone know a reference to a paper by Poincare for this?