# What about the index of this subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ be a subgroup of finite index in $G$, and let $N \colon = \cap_{x \in G} \ xHx^{-1}$. Then $N$ is clearly a subgroup of $G$ which is contained in $H$ and such that $aNa^{-1} = N$ for all $a$ in $G$.

Is $N$ of finite index in $G$? And If so, what can we say about an upper bound for the index of $N$? If not, then can we find a subgroup $N^\prime$ of finite index in  $G$, contained in $H$, and such that $aN^\prime a^{-1} = N^\prime$ for all $a$ in $G$? And what can we say about the index of $N^\prime$ in $G$?

Comment: [This](http://planetmath.org/coreofasubgroup) more or less answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

To your questions: yes, and an upper bound is $\;[G:H]!\;$ (the factorial of the index).

Short explanation: if we denote by $\;X\;$ the *set* of left cosets of $\;H\;$ in $\;G\;$, we make $\;G\;$ act on $\;X\;$ by left shift: $\;x\cdot gH:=(gx)H\;,\;\;g,x\in G\;$.

The above action determines a homomorphism $\;\phi:G\to\text{Sym}_X\cong S_n\;,\;\;n=[G:H]\;$, and it happens to be that $\;\ker\phi=\cap_{g\in G}H^x\;$ is the maximal subgroup normal in $\;G\;$ that is contained in $\;H\;$ .

We also have, of course, that $\;\ker\phi\lhd G\;$ and by the above $\;[G:\ker\phi]\mid |S_n|=n!\;$.

The subgroup $\;\ker\phi\;$ described above is called *the core of* $\;H\;$.

Comment: DonAntonio, can you please give me a more direct proof, wiothout using the action of a group on a set?

Comment: Saaqib, not really: this is the fastest, simplest way I can think of. The normality thing can be checked directly (try it!) and even the finiteness of the index, but the upper bound thing I can't think of any other way. Perhaps there is, it's just that I don't know it.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud The answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680868/poincares-theorem-about-groups) give many different proofs of this fact.

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, that was by the OP who was trying to understand everything else... And perhaps "many different" in my above comment should have been "more than one".

Comment: And now I correct myself, @user1729: lemma four there **is right** . I misread and though that it was $$[G:H]=[G:\cap_{g\in G} H^g]$$

Comment: @DonAntonio I am glad - I thought I twas going mad! Do you want to delete the comment there?

Comment: @user1729, done. Thanks for reminding me...:)