# Two subgroups $H, K$ of coprime and finite index are such that $G = HK$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am asked to prove that if $H, K$ are subgroups of $G$ such that

$$h = [G:H] < \infty, k = [G:K] < \infty, \gcd{(h,k)} = 1$$

then we have

$$G = HK$$

I tried using the fact that

$$|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$$

and concluded I needed to prove $hk|H \cap K| = |G|$ but couldn't go any further.

Immediately above, in the same exercise, I proved that $[H: H\cap K] \leq [G:K]$ if $[G:K]<\infty$ and that equality occurs only when $G = HK$, but it didn't help me in any way.

---

**EDIT**:

Following the hint in the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2526065/329832), we have

$$|G| \leq |HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$$

But obviously $HK \subseteq G$ hence $|G| = |HK|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are almost there (assuming $G$ is finite): hint: $|G:H|$ divides $|G:H \cap K|$, and likewise $|G:K|$ divides $|G:H \cap K|$. Since $|G:H|$ and $|G:K|$ are relatively prime, we have $|G:H| \cdot |G:K|$ divides $|G:H \cap K|$. In particular: $|G:H| \cdot |G:K| \leq |G:H \cap K|$, so |$G| \leq \frac{|H| \cdot |K|}{|H \cap K|}$. Can you finish?

Note: the requirement that $G$ must be finite can be removed. Sketch: in stead of looking at $H$ and $K$ consider their cores - the largest normal subgroups of $G$ contained in $H$, $K$ respectively, written as $core_G(H)$ and $core_G(K)$. $G/core_G(H)$ and $G/core_G(K)$ are finite since the indices of $H$ and $K$ are finite. The problem reduces now to the finite case: $G/(core_G(H) \cap core_G(K))$ which is finite by the so-called Poincaré Lemma (see my remarks [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680868/poincar%C3%A9s-theorem-about-groups)).

Comment: Yes, now I it easy to finish. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I feel that this might be closer to what the exercise wants you to do (for infinite $G$):

You proved above that $|H:H\cap K| < \infty$. Similarly, $|K:H\cap K| < \infty$. We then know $|G:H||H:H\cap K| = |G:K||K:H\cap K| < \infty$. Let
$$n=\frac{|G:H|}{|K:H\cap K|} = \frac{|G:K|}{|H:H\cap K|},$$
we see that $n=1$ because $n$ divides both $|G:H|$ and $|G:K|$. Then we are done, by what you proved above.